# How to view the code behind page of a subform in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2003

Hi im working in Ms Access front end application which uses SQl server 2008 as back end. I want to check the code behind page of the subform from the datasheet view. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Code-Behind doesn't exist in Access, it's referred to as a Module.  Open the page in Design View, and on the Design tab at the top of your screen you should see an icon that reads "View Code".  Click on that and you will see the module behind your form.

Comment: Which version of Access are you using? Surely you are not using 2003, 2007, 2010 and 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Go to DesignView.

Click the subform control twice to activate the subform, then pick code module from the band.